# Install and use helm in multiple k8s containers in same pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have two containers in same pod in k8s. I want to setup helm in first container and use that
setup in second container to deploy helm chart.

Based on some finding is that possible to setup helm client and server in first container and
setup only client in second container?

Thanks.

Comment: "setup helm client and server" ... this is confusing. As of Helm 3: there is no "server" (you mean tiller, right?) part, in helm. Only a client. If you still use Helm 2, get rid of it. v3 has been here for years.

Comment: @SYN Now I am using helm v3.* but still my issue is same. I want setup helm in one container and use that setup in another
 container in same pod for helm chart deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can install helm using the following script commands:

```bash
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
```

### Case One

Now this will get you helm installed but I am not sure if you would want to install helm inside a container in a pod and apply it to another pod as it would only be applicable to this specific case. I think you should use Helm outside the k8s cluster and then deploy it individually.

### Case Two

If you're planning to install a helm chart inside the container, then you should consider using an [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/okteto/helm-installer) like this, where you'll add the helm chart as an operator. You can also choose to install helm with the above mentioned commands in a Ubuntu/Debian instance and add your helm chart, I will attach an example here:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Author: Abhijith Ganesh
# Script for installing helm

curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
helm repo add dokc https://abhijithganesh.tech/dokc-helm-chart/# You can add your helm repo here 
helm repo update
helm install test dokc/dokc-chart -f values.yaml # Your chart goes in here
```

You can make an image like this, export it to your registry and pull it from there.

But again, this will only get you helm inside your pod, I am not sure if you can apply this to another container. You should do it through the controlplane if you want a setup like that.